# What are Spark's (or Hadoop's) rules for saving a dataframe as parquet file?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, parquet

There is a parquet file in the cluster which contains a dataframe and it's size is around 1.65Gb. The cluster's block size is 128Mb.

The first time this file was saved, it was split in 117 parts of varying sizes, none larger than 20.6Mb.

The second time it was saved (read.parquet > write.parquet) it had 19 parts none larger than 102.2Mb but mostly at arround that size except for the last 4, wich were 90, 50, 50 and 30 Mb respectively.

The third time it was saved, starting from the 2nd version it had 18 parts, most around 102Mb except for the last 3 which were 95, 118 and 32Mb respectively.

The DF contains 25 million records with 44 columns. Similar data is generated every day but those were saved in 3 equal parts of 500Mb or similar.
The cluster has 3 data nodes. The spark instance doing the saving each time is used via Zeppelin notebook and it has 10 executors and a driver.

Comment: Is this question mostly out of interest, or does it actually have impact on your processes? (Not trying to be agressive, but curious what the impact of this would be). -- Complete hunch: perhaps a (smart) algorithm is used which keeps data in bins based on a column, and depending on the order with which the records are read, reaches tresholds that trigger the completion of 1 part.

Comment: It is mostly out of curiosity at this point but it's one of those things that seems it will come in handy in the future. The argument pro having as many parts as nodes that I can come up with is that the load is equal and that means equal work for each macine when processing of that data is needed. It should also mean less need to shuffle data between nodes and that is expensive. 
Multiple parts means less control over (or less information about) the location of each part and the load on each node.

Comment: On the other hand I understand that the advantage of having more parts is that it helps paralell processing.

Comment: As you seem to have realized, the question of the optimal part size is a very difficult one. Much more difficult even than a question like 'how does parquet choose part sizes'. This won't help, but consider the impact of these factors: When is it good to have a file per year of data, or per week? What if one node is busy? What if your file is so big that it takes too much ram to process? What if your file is so small that it takes too much overhead to load? What if you decided to make a file per week, and the data is not equally distributed?What if the work per line is not equally distributed?

Comment: Your questions are correct and quite important to ask when deciding how to split a parquet file and maybe the algorithm does take all these into account but I'm a bit more interested in why, considering the same data, it doesn't give the same results. Same data is saved once in 117 parts and then, after I load and save it again, it's saved in 18 parts, while similarly sized and structured data is saved in 3 parts (albeit this last one is done by a cluster with just 3 executors)